# Please delete my closed and unanswered questions

Tags: support, deleted-questions

I have two questions which are closed and unanswered on www.stackoverflow.com.
Please delete these questions... Thank you!

Closed Question Links:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2216641/file-sharing-in-windows-7-closed
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2117188/restore-backup-in-sql-server-closed

Comment: If they're unanswered, you should be able to delete them yourself. And anyway, we can't do anything about them unless you link to them or at least associate your accounts.

Comment: @mmy These are the questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2117188 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2216641. But they're migration questions, not sure if they can be deleted

Comment: @Dow: Ah, I see. Only moderators can delete them because they're locked. But I don't think that it's general practice to delete questions that were migrated somewhere other than Meta, is it?

Comment: They can't be deleted by their author since migrated questions are automatically locked. A moderator will need to step in. @mmyers: since the author knows where they went (and they weren't exactly wildly popular or anything - <100 views apiece), I don't see a problem with them being removed.

Comment: Why do they need to be deleted?

Comment: @Jonathan: perhaps the author does not wish to have useless questions showing up in his profile?

Comment: With all due respect, be careful about what you ask. Besides, many users will still see the posts even if they're deleted.

Answer (score 2):

Once (s)he knows they've been migrated the author does not need the place holders any more - the *author* should be able to delete his/her own migrated questions.

Comment: Questions do not belong to authors the second they're posted, they belong to the community

Comment: It's important they remain for future searches

Comment: @Downvoter: in this case, it isn't. No one is visiting those questions. And they're off-topic. At best, they'll do nothing; at worst, they'll thwart the search rankings of the same questions on Server Fault and Super User.

Answer (score -1):

<strike>First, you could post a link to the questions so it's easy to find them.</strike>

Second, they'll get deleted if they have to, closing them is the first step towards that in the question life cycle.

Third, if they don't have answers, you could delete them yourself clicking on **delete**

**Edit**: Both questions are closed because they were migrated, so they will remain in the original site as placeholders, and to find them in the sister sites.
They should not be deleted

Comment: I see they're migration though, not sure if you can delete those - moderators?